# SET DMY to default in database not working

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem as I need all my tables to be in DMY format, and in DBCC USEROPTIONS the language is set to Danish and DMY as shown in image. But when I run a query it turns into MDY format no matter what I do. I've tried resetting all settings via "Import / Export settings", I've tried ALTER LOGIN and changing language, I've tried changing my WINDOWS system language. Nothing seems to solve my problem. Hopefully somebody can help. I'm running SQL Server 18.

[image]

Comment: There's no image and that setting shouldn't matter at all if you don't use strings instead of dates. Dates have no format. It's *client tools* that use formats when they convert dates to strings for display

Comment: This is expected.   See the example here:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017